# How to handle connect errno in cpp socket programming

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, network-programming

I am new to Network Programming and am currently following [Beej's Guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) to get familiar with this content.

When the book was introducing the `getaddrinfo()` function, it told me about using `gai_strerror()` to interpret the error code returned to readable strings. However, the book doesn't cover the error handle method for `connect()` and I wonder if there is a similar function that would do the same job as what `gai_strerror()` does for `getaddrinfo()`?

Here is my code:

```cpp
    if((status=connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen)) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "connect: %s\n", function_to_be_used(status));

        return 2;
    }
```

Comment: @AlexF Thank you very much for your comment! Now I've finally known that the function actually passes the error code to `errno` instead of returning it.

Comment: `perror("connect")` can also be useful as a quick way to write the error-string associated with errno to stderr.

Comment: This is actually platform-dependant. For instance, there is no `errno` or `strerror()`/`perror()` on Windows, but runtime library vendors may provide their own equivilents. In WinSock programming, since there is no standard `errno`, socket errors are reported by `WSAGetLastError()`, and can be translated into strings using `FormatMessage()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `connect` function reference:

> If the connection or binding succeeds, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.

So, you need the following code:

```
fprintf(stderr, "connect: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

`getaddrinfo` error handling is kind of exception, most API set `errno` on error, which can be converted to error message using `strerror`.

Comment: The `fprintf()` shown is equivlent to just calling `perror("connect")` instead, which will output the same message to stderr.